# How to delete objects in S3 bucket based on contents in another S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

**Context:** I have 2 buckets, bucket A and bucket B. Bucket A had all of its contents placed in Bucket B via the `aws s3 sync` CLI command.

**Problem:** I want to delete all the items in bucket B that also exist in Bucket A, without deleting anything in Bucket A.

E.g.

Bucket A (Source):

1. File R
2. File G
3. File C

Bucket B (Destination):

1. File A
2. File R
3. File G
4. File C
5. File O

^^ **I need to delete all files in the target destination which *do* exist in the source destination, so *only* files R, G, and C need to be deleted from Bucket B.**

**Attempted Solution:** The `aws s3 sync` CLI command includes the flag `--delete`. However, this flag only ensures that any files in the target destination that aren't in the source destination are deleted.

Is there any way to do this using `aws s3 sync`?

Comment: There is no AWS CLI command that can do this -- you'll need to manage it yourself by listing the objects in Bucket A and comparing it to a list objects in Bucket B, then issuing a `DeleteObject()` command. It would be easiest done in a programming language such as Python. Give it a try and let us know if you run into any difficulties.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more about the context? On surface it looks like you do the `sync` and then revert its changes: for example, `sync` copied file R from bucket A to bucket B, and now you want to delete R from B because it is in A.

Comment: @LioniaVasilev exactly, that is my intention.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if I know that all items in A are in B, could I just store the list of objects in A in Python and loop over that list, calling DeleteObject() on each one?

Comment: Be aware that deleting a non-existent S3 object is not considered an error and the deletion will succeed.

Comment: Yes Prithvi, that is the correct approach. You could alternatively make a _list_ of objects to delete and then call `DeleteObjects()` (plural) to delete up to 1000 per API call.

Comment: "exactly, that is my intention." Could you tell a bit about why please? I mean, for example, why not skip copying R from A to B in the first place.

Comment: @LioniaVasilev sure, someone else on my team placed files in the bucket. These files weren't supposed to go in that bucket. Now I need to undo that action by deleting those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this via s3 bucket lifecycle rules where I specified a regex pattern that matched against the necessary files in both buckets.

Using S3 lifecycle rules allows any number of files (in the millions even) to be deleted at midnight UTC and does not incur a cost, unlike the `aws s3 cli` which needs to list objects in order to programmatically delete them (in batches of 1000 at a time)

Answer (score 1):

For a one-off cleanup, if the number of files to delete is small, use the sequence of shell-commands below. Run it with the `--dryrun` flag first, and then, if the output looks as expected, without the flag.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_a/ | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 4 | xargs -t -I % aws s3 rm --dryrun s3://bucket_b/%
```

Explanation of each command is below.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_a/ # List files in the original location.
tr -s ' ' # Remove duplicate whitespaces for the cut command.
cut -d' ' -f 4 # Extract file names.
xargs -t -I % aws s3 rm --dryrun s3://bucket_b/% # Execute rm for each file name in the location with the copies.
```

Alternatively, if the number of files is large, use the the batch delele command below. Please note that the batch command does not have the `--dryrun` option.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_a/ | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 4 | xargs -I % printf '{Key=%}\n' | xargs -n1000 echo | tr ' ' , | xargs -t -I % aws s3api delete-objects --bucket bucket_b --delete 'Objects=[%]'
```

Explanation of the command is below.

```
xargs -I % printf '{Key=%}\n' # Format S3 keys for the batch command.
xargs -n1000 echo # Group the keys in batches, 1000 keys each.
tr ' ' , # Format the groups for the batch command. 
xargs -t -I % aws s3api delete-objects --bucket bucket_b --delete 'Objects=[%]' # Delete the files batch by batch.
```

Comment: I believe using `ls` on a bucket with a huge number of objects can incur costs. 

The way I ended up doing this was via s3 bucekt lifecycle rules where I specified a pattern that matched against the necessary files in both buckets.